# Can embed a SVG pic into a pango string？

Tags: gtk4, pangocairo

I want show some custom unicode character into an string, eg "git" icon, to show in a listbox.

1. draw it with cairo on widget context. But I can not detect ths position which need to over "wwrite".
2. convert svg into pixmap array,then make a tiny font,show it using pango.

If some stick can do this？

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to do this with pango? Because you can achieve the same visual effect using a Gtk.Picture. If you really need to do this with pango, could you show the code you are using?

Comment: I know I can put image and label into a box instead of use listbox.row. But I really want know if I can do this way.